# How to handle multiple nulls?

Tags: java, if-statement

Let's say I have a SOA. Now I make a service call and I get an object which has nested objects as field. Let's say:

```
class A {
 B b;
}
class B {
  C c;
}
class C {
  D d;
}
```

Now if I need to access a field from class D when I get object as a response from a service call i need to perform :

```
if(a == null || a.getB() == null || a.getB().getC() == null || a.getB().getC().getD() == null) {
  throw someexception();
}
```

Is there a graceful way of handling the same predicate?

Comment: I added a missing `== null` I was sure was meant to be there, but roll it back if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
D d = Optional.ofNullable(a)
        .map(A::getB)
        .map(B::getC)
        .map(C::getD)
        .orElseThrow(MyNullException::new);
```

You can also do `orElseGet(D::new)` if you want to use a default value instead.

Comment: That *is* nice, in a modern Java environment. Very nice.

Comment: This is what I needed. This is google guava right or is it the jdk8 one?

Comment: @GloryHunter: JDK8, I've added a link to Peter's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your *specific* example, you're throwing an exception. That being the case, this is apparently an exceptional condition, so we can use exceptions to manage it:

```
D d;
try {
    d = a.getB().getC().getD();
}
catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    throw new SomeException(npe);
}
doYourStuffWith(d);
```

If you **weren't** throwing an exception, you wouldn't do that; you don't want to use exceptions for normal program flow. In that situation, your current check is fine, or you could use more specific exceptions with a series of `if/else`, or in a Java 8 context [do that lovely thing Peter showed us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797485/157247). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
try {

    //Try and do something

} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    //Something was null, therefore an exception was thrown
}
```

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ: Why? Given the OP is throwing an exception.

Comment: If this is wrong, then I'm not sure what OP is getting at?
Also be sure to say WHY i'm wrong if you're going to point something out

Comment: Well, there are about five to six reason...like, really reasons, but let's just state that exceptions are NOT meant to be used to control application flow; although you can use it, like now...but that's just the genesis of many of the commonly flaws and wrong things (practices) that you see in Java source code nowadays

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ: Again: The OP is throwing an exception, so it's *already* an exceptional condition. Absolutely, exceptions for flow control are a Bad Thing™ -- but there's no need to apply that dogma to exceptional conditions. Indeed, this is half the *point* of exceptions, to get checks like this out of the program flow *when appropriate*.

Comment: @DimaMaligin: It would be better, though, if it called out that you wouldn't do this if you weren't treating the `null` case as exceptional.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, let's try one more time. If you know that `a` may throw NPE, why don't you check for it? When you catch, you are sure that something may fail, but not so obvious...otherwise you can be defensive all the way around and put a `try`/`catch` block in the beginning and that's it, you are done! Your thing will bubble up to the top and you won't have any idea what's going on. On the other hand, if you repeat that logic, how is that better than using `label`s, for instance...do you agree on using them too?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ: That's a completely false comparison. I can tell you're not reading and properly considering what I'm saying, so there's no point in my continuing to try to reason with you. Can't intubate the horse.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm no saying catching `NullPointerException` is a good thing, but considering the question that is not out of the question...

Comment: The answer does serve my purpose but it seems a bit off track when one tries to catch NPE.

Comment: The reason for it being odd for me would be that I don't want to get into first throwing an exception and then catching it for the sake of avoiding null checks. Between if and a try catch block I would prefer the first.

Comment: @GloryHunter the point is that you dont have to `throw it` as the aswer said in the catch block "Something was null, therefore an exception was thrown". that meens exactly what it said. and you dont need to `throw` it.

Comment: Yes and there lies my bigger part of problem. Let's extend my original problem. I want to make 5-6 service calls with all of them returning me complex objects. And then there are operations between these service calls that are prone to null pointer exception. So now, instead of sanitizing the response before translating, this piece of code will also save me from the NPE other than what I wanted. I know its arguable but best practices are often so.

Comment: @GloryHunter bare in mind that the answers you get are only as good as the question.. so when you "extend" on the question you have to keep in mind that only **YOU** know exactly what you need and the rest are just volunteers.

Comment: Agreed. My point was not shooting heads but just a pure discussion. I am sorry if I got it wrong somewhere. Cheers :)